# Coordinates inside axis environment (TikZ)

Tags: pgfplots

I am really confused with how coordinates work inside the axis environment. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4, xmax=4,
        ymin=-.02,ymax=1,
        width=0.5\textwidth,
        height=0.33\textwidth,
        xtick distance=1,
        xlabel={Ability [Logits]},
        ylabel={Probability}]
        \addplot[domain=-4.9:4.9,blue,samples=200,thick]
        {1/(1+exp(-(1.3*x-2.2)))};

    %%%% Where is this node? %%%%
    \node[rectangle,fill=white] (a) at (2,.5) {\footnotesize{\textcolor{blue}{label}}};
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the code above node (a) is nowhere to be seen in the tikz picture. I would expect it to appear at the specified location (2,0.5). Apparently it does not work this way and I do not understand what is going on exactly.

Comment: By default the coordinates of the basic TikZ macros `\node`, `\draw` etc. are *not* in the coordinate system of the `axis`. Either add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or some higher valid version number, see `pgfplots` manual) to change the default, or prepend `axis cs:` in the coordinates, e.g. `(axis cs:2, 0.5)`.

Comment: That is intersting to know! "axis cs:" is all I needed to know. Thank you! Unfortunately I can't give your answer the checkmark since you only commented.

Comment: I commented because several similar questions have been asked before, I meant to find a duplicate.

Comment: @YellowCake the main problem here is that you ignored the pgfplots warning about not setting a compat level...

Comment: Another benefit of setting the `compat` level is that the position of the ylabel will be improved, moved closer to the axis.